# Create new button for each email c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email, button

Hi i have the following code that allows me to create a new list view item for every email in my inbox, my question is how would i create a new button for each email instead of a list view item.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < bundle.MessageCount - 0; i++)
{
  email = bundle.GetEmail(i);

  System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem itmp = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(email.From);
  System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem itms1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmp, email.Subject);
  System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem itms2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmp, email.FromName);

  itmp.SubItems.Add(itms1);
  itmp.SubItems.Add(itms2);

  listView1.Items.Add(itmp).Tag = i;

  richTextBox1.Text = email.Body;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a button the same way - it inherits from `Control`:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Button button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
button.Text = "My button";

button.OnClick += new EventHandler(myButton_Click); // myButton_Click should exist

listView1.Items.Add(button);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer how would i give the button name the name of the email

Comment: @Shane121 - Look at the documentation for [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx). It has `Name` and `Text` properties that you can assign these values to.

Comment: But how would i go about creating a new button for each email with each messages name

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `new Button()`, set properties and add event handlers, then add it to a container's `Controls` collection.